# Tokenization of a string using C#

Tags: c#, regex, tokenize

I would like to tokenize a string that contains a definition of a function prototype using C# code (i.e. the tokenization is implemented in C#).

A generic function prototype looks like:

```
[String var1, String var2, Integer var3], Double[] var4, Double[,] var5 = MyFunction(Dates[] dates, Double[,] prices, Double upperBoundWeight)
```

I am relatively new to C#. My attempt splits the sentence to a right and left based on the "=" character and I tokenize them separately. The code looks like:

```
string[] words = exampleString.Split(new string[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Notice the whitespace after the "," where I force users to use the space in the input definition. Looking only the string for my LHS of the my string input, I get

```
[String var1
String var2
Integer var3]
Double[] var4
Double[,] var5
```

which is very close to what I am looking for except that I would like to group var1, var2 and var3 (i.e. it should work with nested expressions 1 level deep).

The code is really fragile as missing whitespace, etc. can cause it to break.

Surely there must be a nicer way. I tried Regex.Split but that expression got hairy real quick so before I charged that windmill, I figured I would ask here.

What is a nice way to tokenize the given string?
Are there any standard libraries or modules that can help with this?

Comment: Please research on the syntax of the function prototype. Without it, you are going to get a bunch of half-working solution.

Comment: You'll need to look into state machines. And as @nhahtdh said, your function definition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I get to define the syntax. The syntax in this case is a free-form string that the user provides that indicates how the inputs and outputs to a UDF are marshalled and collected. In this case, the function MyFunction accepts 3 inputs, a column of dates, a table of prices and a single scalar upperbound contraint. It returns a total of 5 outputs, the first 3 being scalars, the 4th being a column and a last one being a table. The decoration [] around the first 3 collect them into a single table. Yes, it is less than ideal but it works and I plan to stick with it unless I hear a better idea.

Comment: In other words, the syntax stinks. I know it. But do you have a better idea?